# I can't combine adjacent periods in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by, window-functions

I work in PostgreSQL.

I have a table that stores info about clients and their status in different groups. I want a select query that will show this information like periods instead of event structure. So it will show client_id, moment_start, moment_end, status_group and status (boolean). Although I can use the lead(), I get results for a client where the next period with the same status is another record while I want to get periods where the status changes from row to row (by client_id and status_group). In reality, I use timestamp(6) instead of date.

What should I write in the query to achieve that?

Original table:

| id | client_id | moment | status_group | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-01 | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-05-05 | A | TRUE |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-05-07 | A | FALSE |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-06-10 | A | TRUE |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-07-10 | A | TRUE |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-05-10 | B | FALSE |

Required table:

| client_id | moment_start | moment_end | status_group | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-07 | A | TRUE |
| 1 | 2021-05-07 | 2021-06-10 | A | FALSE |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 | NULL | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 2021-07-10 | NULL | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 2021-05-10 | NULL | B | FALSE |

I tried:

```
SELECT
client_id,
moment AS moment_start
LEAD(moment) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, status_group ORDER BY moment) AS moment_end,
status_group,
status
FROM table
ORDER BY client_id, moment_start
```

The table I got:

| client_id | moment_start | moment_end | status_group | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-05 | A | TRUE |
| 1 | 2021-05-05 | 2021-05-07 | A | TRUE |
| 1 | 2021-05-07 | 2021-06-10 | A | FALSE |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 | NULL | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 2021-07-10 | NULL | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 2021-05-10 | NULL | B | FALSE |

Comment: Present the original table as executable SQL to minimize the effort required by others to setup the problem and also show the desired output (see [mre]). Your query is a usable starting point to get the results you're seeking. The next step is to combine the results of this query such that contiguous moments with the same `client_id`, `status_group`, and `status` are reduced to single rows having the minimum `moment_start` and maximum `moment_end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query demonstrates an approach to extract only status changes:

```
WITH
    example_data (id, client_id, moment, status_group, status) AS (
        VALUES
            (1, 1, '2021-05-01'::TIMESTAMP, 'A', TRUE),
            (2, 1, '2021-05-05'::TIMESTAMP, 'A', TRUE),
            (3, 1, '2021-05-07'::TIMESTAMP, 'A', FALSE),
            (4, 1, '2021-06-10'::TIMESTAMP, 'A', TRUE),
            (5, 2, '2021-07-10'::TIMESTAMP, 'A', TRUE),
            (6, 2, '2021-05-10'::TIMESTAMP, 'B', FALSE)
    ),
    changes AS (
        SELECT
            d.id,
            d.client_id,
            d.moment,
            d.status_group,
            d.status,
            (d.status_group, d.status) IS DISTINCT FROM (LAG(d.status_group) OVER client_moment,
                                                         LAG(d.status) OVER client_moment) AS client_status_changed
        FROM
            example_data d
        WINDOW
            client_moment AS (PARTITION BY d.client_id, d.status_group ORDER BY d.moment)
    )
SELECT
    c.client_id,
    c.moment,
    c.status_group,
    c.status
FROM
    changes c
WHERE
    c.client_status_changed
ORDER BY
    c.client_id, c.moment;
```

The following result is produced:

| client_id | moment | status_group | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | A | true |
| 1 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 | A | false |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 | A | true |
| 2 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | B | false |
| 2 | 2021-07-10 00:00:00 | A | true |

The query uses a named window frame to reduce redundant code. The query can easily be modified to return include both a `moment_start` and a `moment_end` by using the `LAG` function in the main query.

Comment: There is a required correction in the block of the window definition: there should be a partition by client_id and status_group otherwise it would mistakenly take into account other status_group's statuses.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MaksimP., I've approved your edit of my answer. When creating example data and output, try to ensure that all requirements are excercised just as should be done when creating unit tests. I'm pleased that you took the time to review and comment on my answer. I've corrected the column name from `group` to `status_group` in your original post.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo, now everything is right.